# How to add permalink icons to admonition?

Tags: python-sphinx

In documents I made using sphinx, there are clickable permalink icons for each chapter and section.

How do I put this icon for admonitions? I think I have to write an extension but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting or extension to do this. See the tutorial for writing an extension http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/tutorial.html